# how to make my vm reachable from hosts within same network

Tags: networking, kali-linux, virtualbox

**Context:**

I want to do a reverse shell POC, so I am using Kali Linux on virtual box hosted on a Windows machine. On the same network my Windows machine hosted, there is a Linux machine that I want to gain a reverse shell on it. Before doing so, I was checking if ping is working fine between the victim machine (another host) and the attack machine (Kali). Since it's a reverse shell, then the victim machine will initiate the connection to my machine (Kali), thus ping from victim to Kali is a prerequisite for this POC.

**Setup:**

I am using VirtualBox with Kali Linux, I set the network mode as bridged.
Now I have IP with same range as my laptop (host).

IPs:

host IP: 10.36.56.178
vm IP: 10.36.56.234
another host IP: 10.25.1.29

From laptop to my vm: Ping works

From vm to my laptop: Ping works

From another host to laptop: Ping works

From laptop to another host : Ping works

From vm to another host: Ping works

From another host to vm: Ping **DOES NOT WORK**

**Issue:**

I cannot ping from the victim host (aka another host) to the Kali machine, I am using wrong network settings ?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich noted. I will ask it on stackoverflow